# I am unable to load Image in Javascript file and I am facing this issue - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

[image]

I have made image src in html and I am trying to change that image on click from Javascript in a Javascript file. Can someone please help me please check image  here for detail of the error?

Comment: Share the javascript code to get an idea of the issue

Comment: Hi there, try going to that URL to see if that image is there, if you can't find it then there's likely a typo in the URL.

Comment: Check the file names and locations; they may differ from what JavaScript is trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

typically its an error in the syntax of the URL it looks like you are trying to retrieve the images from the root directory of your site. You are also passing the port information through that URL btw that might be the issue too